# True of False: If $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a+$ and $g(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, then $g(x)/f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to a+$

Tags: real-analysis

True of False:

If $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a+$ and $g(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, then $g(x)/f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to a+$.

I am having trouble trying to prove how this could be true (as I can't find a counterexample to show that it is false).  Any suggestions to help me get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False. Consider $g(x) = 1$, $f(x) = x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ and $a = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Are both of those functions positive for all $x$? You know that if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = +\infty$ and $f(x) \leq g(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = +\infty$. In your problem, use the fact that $1 \leq g(x) \ \forall x$ and you can solve it if $f$ is positive for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.